# TraverseTreeParallelForEach MSDN sample Exception

Tags: c#

I am using this code [TraverseTreeParallelForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff477033.aspx)

Sometimes i mysteriously get Aggregated Exception. Array index out of bounds exception at Add(T). I am using this for my backup program.

```
public List<string> execute(string filterlist, string[] drives) 
    {
        List<string> returnfiles = new List<string>(); // final list

        foreach (string drive in drives)
        {
            foreach (string filter in filterlist.Split(','))
            {
                TraverseTreeParallelForEach(drive, filter, (f) =>
                {
                    returnfiles.Add(f);
                });
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Returnfiles count " + returnfiles.Count);
        returnfiles.RemoveAll(item => item == null); //remove nulls
        return returnfiles;
    }
```

Q2. Currently to search 5 drives ~400GB it takes 1-1.5min, so any other way to speedup search or any tweaks to for code.

Q3. My program first lists & then compresses files in list. Can Producer-Consumer implementation improve total time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your access to the returnfiles collection is not synchronized. The following code does fix that.

public List execute(string filterlist, string[] drives) 
    {
        List returnfiles = new List(); // final list
        object lockObj = new object();

```
    foreach (string drive in drives)
    {
        foreach (string filter in filterlist.Split(','))
        {
            TraverseTreeParallelForEach(drive, filter, (f) =>
            {
                lock(lockObj)
                {
                   returnfiles.Add(f);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Returnfiles count " + returnfiles.Count);
```

// should not be necessary        returnfiles.RemoveAll(item => item == null); //remove nulls
        return returnfiles;
    }

The MSDN Sample code is correct but you do modify a collection from several threads which will cause random errors during the add operation because the List collection is not threadsafe by itself. You can either lock the collection or your can use some thread safe alternative.

Yes you can use a producer consumer pattern to speed things up. You can e.g. use a Queue instead of a list wihth the lock and spin up some tasks to compress your files while you are searching for them. This will give you at most a speed increase of 1-1.5 minutes of your total backup time which can be worth it or not depending on how much you do backup.

Another thing is that since you are reading from 5 discs you could create one queue per disc so you can max out the IO bandwidth of the discs you do read from. This will only help if the target backup device can handle then increased IO and if your SATA or or whatever bus the drives are connected to can handle the IO generated by the discs.